# insertable, updatable attributes behavior persisting the object

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I have an Entity as follow

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DATMLAUENDCTT")
public class EnderecoContatoLaudoEntity implements Serializable {

    /** A Constante serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** O id. */
    @EmbeddedId
    private EnderecoContatoLaudoEntityPK id;

    /** O nome contato. */
    @Column(name="CTTNOM")
    private String nomeContato;

    /** O Codigo ddd telefone contato. */
    @Column(name="CTTTELDDDCOD")
    private BigDecimal codigoDDDTelefoneContato;

    /** O numero telefone contato. */
    @Column(name="CTTTELNUM")
    private BigDecimal numeroTelefoneContato;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to TipoTelefoneEntity
    /** O tipo telefone entity. */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="TELTIPSEQNUM",referencedColumnName="TELTIPSEQNUM")
    private TipoTelefoneEntity tipoTelefoneEntity;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to EnderecoLaudoEntity
    /** O endereco laudo entity. */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="LAUSEQNUM", referencedColumnName="LAUSEQNUM"),
        @JoinColumn(name="ENDTIPSEQNUM", referencedColumnName="ENDTIPSEQNUM")
    })
    private EnderecoLaudoEntity enderecoLaudoEntity;
```

And it's embedded id as follows:

```
@Embeddable
public class EnderecoContatoLaudoEntityPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    /** A Constante serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** Coloquei os nomes das colunas que não vieram quando foi gerada pelo RAD. */
    @Column(name = "LAUSEQNUM", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private long numeroSequenciaLaudo;

    /** O numero sequencia tipo endereco. */
    @Column(name = "ENDTIPSEQNUM", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private long numeroSequenciaTipoEndereco;

    /** O numero sequencia tipo telefone. */
    @Column(name = "TELTIPSEQNUM", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private long numeroSequenciaTipoTelefone;
```

**My question is, why does the insert does not work when I try to to persist the entity ?**

The error tells me that TELTIPSEQNUM is null.
But I'm setting the object `tipoTelefoneEntity` which correspond to column `TELTIPSEQNUM`.

Now, when I remove the insertable = false, updatable = false, like this:

/** O numero sequencia tipo telefone. */
    @Column(name = "TELTIPSEQNUM")
    private long numeroSequenciaTipoTelefone;

Then the persist works.

**Shouldn't the insert use the `TELTIPSEQNUM` from the object `TipoTelefoneEntity`, that is outside the embedded id object?**

Answer (score 0):

Simple, if you use

```
insertable = false
```

The JPA client will not insert that value in the new object, that how should work
From documentation:

```
public abstract boolean insertable
(Optional) Whether the column is included in SQL INSERT statements generated by the persistence provider
```

Comment: But in the entity EnderecoContatoLaudoEntity there is no updatable and insertable in the TipoTelefoneEntity property, so it should add the column to the statement, right? That's what I'm asking. @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="TELTIPSEQNUM",referencedColumnName="TELTIPSEQNUM")
 private TipoTelefoneEntity tipoTelefoneEntity;